# Помогите изменить вывод ответа

Tags: pascal, freepascal, pascalabc.net

### Для лабы задание я решил а вот вывод правильно оформить не получается, помогите пожалуйста

**вывод должен получится таким: [1;1,4,4]**
Количество элементов вывода может изменятся в этом то и моя основная проблема

```
uses crt;
Var
n: string;

procedure confrac(n:string);
Var
a,b,c,col,err,zoz: integer;
g, h: string;
sPos:=1;
    begin
        sPos := PosEx('/',n,sPos);
        g:= Copy(n, 1, spos-1);
        h:= Copy(n, (sPos+1), length(n));
        val(g,a,err);
        val(h,b,err);
while a>1 do
    begin
        writeln(a div b);
        c:=a mod b;
        a:=b;
        b:=c;
    end;
end;
begin
confrac('38/21');
end.
```

На данный момент у меня получилось сделать вывод таким:

 **1
1
1
4**

Comment: для начала замените `writeln` на `write` ну а дальше сами выведите нужные символы (пробел, скобка, запятые).

Comment: [1;1,4,4], а это нормально что сначала разделитель это `;` а потом уже запятые пошли?

Comment: да в этом то и проблема

Comment: просто в моем понимании `;` это разделитель между значениями массива. А вот запятую можно вопринимать двояко - и как разделитель и как дробную часть (хотя число с 3мя запятыми эт чет странное)

Comment: @pavel если бы 1 разделителем не был бы    ** ;** а потом запятые, я бы так и сделал

Comment: наверно стоит сделать отдельную процедуру которая обернет вам ответ в нужную форму

Comment: я думал создать массив и заполнять его значениями `a div b`примерно так:`write('[',mas[0],';');` <br> `for i:=1 to d do write(mas[i],',');`<br> а d увеличивать внутри цыкла когда `a div b`

Comment: но у меня не вышло это реализовать

Comment: Я прошу меня извинить, но вы точно уверены что должен получиться именно такой вывод (мб вы опечатались где-то) ? Просто это тогда не массив уж точно (в котором все разделители одинаково стилизованы) и это не будет просто массив значений 1 1 4 4 .

Comment: @alexoander  `Напишите процедуру confrac (n), которая превращает действительное число n в цепную дробь. Процедура выводит на печать результат в виде строки: [a0; a1, a2, a3, ..]`

Comment: У вас неправильный вход. Должно быть число, а не дробь

Comment: @vp_arth  нет у меня все верно на вход должна подаваться строка `Цепная дробь для числа 38/21 запишется в виде [1;1,4,4]`

Comment: `confrac (n), которая превращает действительное число n` Подавать на вход нужно как есть `confrac(38/21)`

Comment: `для числа 38/21`, в примере программе передается  `38/21` , как вы `38/21` передадите в integer или real?

Comment: По вашему, `'38/21'` - действительное число?

Comment: @vp_arth `Множество действительных чисел объединяет в себе множество рациональных и иррациональных чисел. Обозначается множество действительных чисел .`[ссылка](http://www.webmath.ru/poleznoe/formules_18_14.php)

Comment: @vp_arth возможно само задание сформулировано не правильно, но это не моя вина, я должен из`'38/21'` сделать `[1;1,4,4]`

Comment: Задание сформулировано предельно точно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предполагаю, что решение должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
procedure confrac(n: double);
Var 
  a, x, eps : double;
begin
  eps := 0.000001;
  write('[');
  a := floor(n);
  x := n - a;
  write(a, '; ');

  while x > eps do
  begin
    a := floor(1/x);
    x := 1/x - a;
    write(a);
    if x > eps then write(', ');
  end;
  writeln(']');
end;
begin
  confrac(38/21);
end.
```

[Источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C)

Comment: `Ошибка времени выполнения: Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для Int32.` Вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Да, это скорее всего оно самое. У меня нет компилятора паскаль, чтобы проверить)

Comment: Добавил эпсилон, должно работать

Comment: решение верное спасибо